Frankenstein’s Conscience conflicting with tabular environment? How to patch?
I'm using compsci and friends for a LaTeX course. But the following MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{compsci}
\begin{document}
 Well, the following works: ``\cs\_''
 % but there's an extra space before closing "

 \begin{tabular}{ll}
   \cs\_ & still fine
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
   \cs\_ & but broken
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}

…produces the following when trying to compile with pdfTeX
$ pdflatex test0.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test0.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-08>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/compsci.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/abbrevs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/moredefs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/slemph.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/slemph.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/abbrevs.cfg
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty

Package relsize Warning: Failed to get list of defined font sizes.
(relsize)                Size scaling will attempt arbitrary sizes..

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/alltt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/lips.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/shortvrb.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/titles.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/titles.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/compsci.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test0.aux)
! Use of \@array doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.11  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                            
? q
OK, entering \batchmode

I also have the same table issue when replacing \cs{} with \code{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{compsci}
\begin{document}
 Well, the following works: ``\code{\_}''
 % and there's no extra space before closing "

 \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \code{\_} & still fine
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \code{\_} & but broken
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}

Well, rereading the package documentation, the pairs \code{}/|| and \cs{}/\cmd{} are sort of re-implementation of \verb|| …but the following trial is successful
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
 Well, the following works: ``\verb|\_|''
 % and there's no extra space before closing "

 \begin{tabular}{ll}
   \verb|\_| & still fine
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
   \verb|\_| & not broken
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}

Any idea how to fix that? I’ve been able to use to following alternative (thanks to greg for trick)
- \usepackage{compsci}
+ %\usepackage{compsci}
+ \providecommand*{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
+ \providecommand*{\code}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}

but not (it’s like package definitions are seen at some point, despite my overlay)
- %\usepackage{compsci}
+ \usepackage{compsci}
- \providecommand*{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
+ \renewcommand*{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
- \providecommand*{\code}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
+ \renewcommand*{\code}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}

I don’t want to just remove the package ’cause I’m using many others commands and environments that should be rewritten then. In another hand, I don’t know if the fix I’m asking for, here, is easier and/or less work.
Tia

Not related, but \documentclass{minimal} is too stripped down for minimal working examples.  Use article instead.

Working the same here, but question edited to change class ;)

Do I get it right: The files from 2001/2006 have problems with latest Latex versions?

Good point: I have to found and test against older LaTeX versions :s

Can you post the log rather than terminal output? The log includes version information for packages.

You don't get an error? When I try to compile your first example, I get ! Use of \@array doesn't match its definition. \@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a { #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... l.1152  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}.

It breaks with TL 2020. That's the oldest I have locally.

the sty does makes | a shortcut for \verb (with \MakeShortVerb \|),  this breaks on your vertical lines in the tabular. That is not new, it brokes also in texlive 2013. Use \cs{\_}  to avoid the space, the style inserts a space by purpose in some cases.

Thanks @UlrikeFischer I read about |…| in the manual but didn't think it should impact my usage elsewhere and especially in table format. So, a fix would be to remove that shortcut?

Hi @cfr I got the same error ! Use of \@array doesn't match its definition. \@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {                                                   #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... It's mentioned in the question (the end of terminal output, but I'll edit to include the log file instead)

@gildux Sorry, I missed that.

Hello all. Sorry, I've been busy and a bit far from Internet. Here's a follow up: I've made a copy of compsci.sty then modified this later by commenting lines 448 (\DeleteShortVerb{\|} but not sure that's needed) and 506 (\MakeShortVerb{\| sure this one is important) After that, I'm able to compile the same examples, with tabular having vertical bars. I don't know if I did the correct thing but no more issue for my usecase.
